# Integrate multiple web applications

Tags: spring, iframe, playframework, integration

I have multiple web applications in playframework, spring mvc and cakephp.
What is the most secure way to integrate these independent web applications.

I want to have a common application in which these will be integrated.
These applications should be able to communicate through this common application.

Is there any better technique than iframes?

Answer (score 1):

Use REST API endpoints to communicate over HTTP. Since you mention safety, use HTTPS.

REST API:

> It's stateless, so use TOKEN-based authorization.

If your application that runs in cakephp has customer data, then make an endpoint(route) like:

```
if(request.method == 'GET'){
    //Add condition for Authorization
    data = fetchDataFromDB()
    sendResponse(data)
}
```

Which fetches the customer data from your database and sends it to the client

It then can be fetched in your application that runs in play framework by AJAX request(client-side) or your server can request by:

```
GET /customerData
```

Note:

> Necessary headers should be sent for authorization and also CORS functionality should be enabled in your servers.

Comment: Thanks, But I wanted to know a good approach to integrate their views also, not only data.

Comment: You can do something like [bigpipe](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919/) or maybe [SSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) and [ESI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes).